# How to send user from one to another html page on spring-boot

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc

I have a simple menu with one link to authorization page. But i get 404 when browser sends me to authorization page. And also in IDE spring cant find related tags in UserController for sign_up, sign_in and authorization.

UserController:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("authorization/authorization")
public class UserController {
private final UserRepo repo;
private final String mainPage= "lobby/lobby";
@PostMapping("/sign_up")
    public String register(@RequestBody UserDao user, Model model){
Optional<UserDao> userFromDB=repo
        .findAll()
        .stream()
        .filter(u->u.getLogin().equalsIgnoreCase(user.getLogin()))
        .findAny();
if(!userFromDB.isEmpty())return "authorization/re-sign_up";
repo.save(user);
model.addAttribute("login",user.getLogin());
return mainPage;
}
@PostMapping("/sign_in")
    public String signIn(@RequestParam("login") String login,
        @RequestParam("pass") String pass, @RequestParam("email") String email, Model model){
UserDao tempUser= repo.findByPassAndName(login, pass);
model.addAttribute("login",login);
model.addAttribute("pass",pass);
return tempUser!=null?mainPage:"authorization/re-sign_in";
}
}
```

lobby.html

```
<a href="../authorization/authorization.html">sign_in</a>
```

authorization.html

```
<a href="sign_in.html">sign_in</a> or <a href="sign_up.html">sign_up</a>
```

im just learning web-mvc, so i dont really understand these link relations.